# Passing Variable from Another Module's Function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new with JS/NodeJs.

I managed to authenticate with Google Firebase

**verifyFirebase.js:**

```
  function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
    if (req.header('auth-token')) {
      admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.header('auth-token'))
        .then((decodedToken) => {
            //return uid
            let uid = decodedToken.uid
          next()
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          res.status(403).send('Unauthorized')
        });
    } else {
       
      res.status(403).send('Unauthorized')
    }
  }



module.exports.checkAuth = checkAuth;
```

and I'm using it on the another files as below;

**routes.js**

```
const verify_firebase = require('./verifyFirebase').checkAuth;


router.get('/', verify_firebase, (req,res) => {
    res.json("verified");
})
```

The "/" route is protected with verify_firebase function coming from verifyFirebase.js.
How can I access **uid** variable from routes.js? Because I need to access this uid within secured route.

Comment: one thing that i think you can do is to add `uid` to the request object

Comment: @MeBottleOScrumpy how could it be possible? It would be really saving me if you can share sample code.

Comment: What is `router.get`? Are you using express.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this might work

```js
 function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
    if (req.header('auth-token')) {
      admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.header('auth-token'))
        .then((decodedToken) => {
            //return uid
            let uid = decodedToken.uid
            req.decoded = {
              uid:uid
            };
          next()
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          res.status(403).send('Unauthorized')
        });
    } else {
       
      res.status(403).send('Unauthorized')
    }
  }



module.exports.checkAuth = checkAuth;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `uid` variable as `req.uid` and use it within your `routes.js` file, like this:

**verifyFirebase.js**

```
...
        .then((decodedToken) => {
            //return uid
            req.uid = decodedToken.uid
          next()
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
...
```

**routes.js**

```
const verify_firebase = require('./verifyFirebase').checkAuth;


router.get('/', verify_firebase, (req,res) => {
    console.log('my uid:', req.uid);
    res.json("verified");
})
```

Please, keep in mind that if you're gonna use typescript, you'll also need to define the correct type for it.